# Encountering unrecognized selector sent to instance error" when trying to write a post to Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently working on a uiViewController that allows the user to write a post inside a textView then submit it to Firebase Realtime Database using a button function called "sendPost". I am encountering this error:

"Thread 1: Exception: "-[Healthify.CreatePostViewController sendPost:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f965682cee0"

I have gone through the Firebase setup instructions multiple times and I have everything correct. I know my segue between the storyboard button and my view controller is functional.

I am not ultra-familiar with this error so I am wondering if it is an error with my code or if maybe my Realtime Database is not setup correctly.

```
@IBAction func sendPost(_ sender: Any, textView: UITextView) {
        let postRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts").childByAutoId()

        let postObject = [
            "text": textView.text!,
            "timestamp": [".sv":"timestamp"]
        ] as [String:Any]

        postRef.setValue(postObject, withCompletionBlock: {error, ref in
            if error == nil{
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }//end of if
            else {
                //handle error
            }//end of else
        })
    }
```

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R95eeehl8Ck) for reference. I have only got from 0:0-2:50 on it. Does anybody have an idea of a potential solution?

Comment: Add the code where you are passing this function as selector.

Comment: It generally helps us to help you when you step through your code, determine what line is throwing the error and then include that information in your question. Also, this isn't going to work `@IBAction func sendPost(_ sender: Any, textView: UITextView)` as it doesn't have an action event like that.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my issue was that in my IBAction function for my button I had called in textView: UITextView which, as stated in the comment, cannot be done. I deleted that and now everything works fine.